Pattern matching in python to catch enum-flag combination
When using Flags in Python, pattern matching only catch direct equality and not inclusion. It can be circumvented with a condition and an in however, provided you catch the 0 flag before if you consider it a special case:
from enum import Flag

class Test(Flag):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = ONE | TWO
    NONE = 0

def match_one(pattern):
    match pattern:
        case Test.THREE:
            print(pattern, 'Three')
        case Test.ONE:
            print(pattern, 'ONE')
        case v if v in Test.THREE:
            print(pattern, 'in THREE')
        case _:
            print(pattern, 'Other')


Test.ONE ONE
Test.TWO in THREE
Test.THREE Three
Test.NONE in THREE

However, using such condition is limiting when using multiple flags.
A minimal example would be trying to match OBJ_1 with TYPE_1 (either ATTR_1 or ATTR_2, or TYPE_1) or OBJ_2 with TYPE_2 (either ATTR_3, ATTR_4, or TYPE_2) (the problem is not limited to such a simple case, but it's a good minimal representation)
class Flag_1(Flag):
    OBJ_1 = 1
    OBJ_2 = 2
    NONE = 0

class Flag_2(Flag):
    ATTR_1 = 1
    ATTR_2 = 2
    ATTR_3 = 4
    ATTR_4 = 8
    TYPE_1 = ATTR_1 | ATTR_2
    TYPE_2 = ATTR_3 | ATTR_4
    NONE = 0

which can be done as
match flag1, flag2:
    case Flag_1.NONE, _ | _, Flag_2.NONE:
        print('Useless')
    case (Flag_1.OBJ_1, c) if c in Flag_1.TYPE_1:
        print('Do 1')
    case (Flag_1.OBJ_2, c) if c in Flag_1.TYPE_2:
        print('Do 1')
    case _:
        print('Other stuff')

or
match flag1, flag2:
    case Flag_1.NONE, _ | _, Flag_2.NONE:
        print('Useless')
    case (Flag_1.OBJ_1, Flag_2.ATTR_1 | Flag_2.ATTR_2) \
        | (Flag_1.OBJ_2, Flag_2.ATTR_3 | Flag_2.ATTR_4):
        print('Do 1')
    case _:
        print('Other stuff')

However solution 1 is limiting when there are some more combinations and adds many line which repeats the same operation. Solution 2 on the other hand is limiting if TYPE_1 contains let's say 10 flags, as it would be a very long line.
something like below is not possible with pattern matching (and would be more adapted to a if statement I think)
case (Flag_1.OBJ_1, c) if c in Flag_2.TYPE_1 \
    | (Flag_1.OBJ_2, c) if c in Flag_2.TYPE_2:  # invalid syntax

and the following does not works as explained earlier due to the way pattern matching works
case (Flag_1.OBJ_1, Flag_2.TYPE_1) \
    | (Flag_1.OBJ_2, Flag_2.TYPE_2) \ 

Is there a better way than solution 1 with doing one case for each combinations despite all having the same outcome, or using an if statement, to match combined Flag?

The match-case pattern is very powerful, but I don't think it is the right solution here.  You can accomplish this is in a much more understandable way using a few if-statements.  The nice part of using flags is that you can check for membership to the combined flags using &.
def check_two(flag1: Flag_1, flag2: Flag_2):
    if (not flag1) or (not flag2):
        return 'Useless'
    if (flag1 & Flag_1.OBJ_1) and (flag2 & Flag_2.TYPE_1):
        return 'Obj-1, Type-1'
    if (flag1 & Flag_1.OBJ_2) and (flag2 & Flag_2.TYPE_2):
        return 'Obj-2, Type-2'
    return 'Other mix'


I'd just point out in your example that, as you are using & rather than in, you are catching Flag_1.OBJ_1 | Flag_1.OBJ_2 in the first if, which in would not do as it returns True for total inclusion rather than returning the intersection.

I agree if is nicer here. I appreciate the match  cause it's very readable for simpler case (like just matching Flag_1.OBJ). I take from your answer, that the best solution (in readability) is still to have multiple branches resulting in the same operation, which is slightly annoying but oh well. And even if you group them under the same if line, it has the same issue of being very long and "ugly".

I am sorry, I don't understand the first comment.  What is the issue?

With Flag, you can pass a flag which value is Flag_1.OBJ_1 | Flag_1.OBJ_2. Like Flag_2.TYPE_1 which is a mix of two flags. flag1 in checked_flag check that all "component" of flag1 are also in checked_flag while flag1 & checked_flag return the intersection of flag1 and checked_flag, which means if they have one common flag, it's True. Your answer is not incorrect, but it slightly changes, in this case, the way the flag are handled

Ah, I see.  Yes, this would have be modified for more complex examples.
